# Azure Devops Apple App Store Release.Missing value for the attribute 'whatsNew'

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, fastlane

I have tried to submit it for review and release it automatically to App Store Connect.
I used to Apple App Store Release stage from the marketplace. For Testflight upload, the bundle works as well. I tried to test it to release automatically and submit for review but every time failed with the same error  **You must provide a value for the attribute 'whatsNew' with this request** The question is can I use to already uploaded Screenshots Descriptions, Copyrights, etc, for now, were manually created for every review but I want to automate it. Also when I click on **Skip Binary Upload failed**. I can't find proper documentation for Devops Apple App Store Release. Its confused this production track.Many thanks!

Here is my stage screenshot
[Azure DevOps Release Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7fQG.png)

```
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3861260Z +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3862270Z |                                                      deliver 2.205.1 Summary                                                       |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3864990Z +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3865620Z | force                                        | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3866070Z | precheck_include_in_app_purchases            | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3866560Z | api_key_path                                 | /Users/runner/work/_temp/api_key9Z88UF88N9.json                                     |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3867080Z | app_identifier                               | com.bundle.id                                                         |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3867630Z | ipa                                          | /Users/runner/work/r1/a/_bundle_CI/Bundle IPA/Bundle.ipa
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3868130Z | platform                                     | ios                                                                                 |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3868510Z | skip_metadata                                | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3868900Z | skip_screenshots                             | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3869680Z | submit_for_review                            | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3870340Z | automatic_release                            | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3871120Z | submission_information.add_id_info_uses_idfa | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3872330Z | screenshots_path                             | ./screenshots                                                                       |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3873060Z | metadata_path                                | ./metadata                                                                          |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3873660Z | app_version                                  | 1.0.149                                                                             |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3874270Z | edit_live                                    | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3874850Z | use_live_version                             | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3875480Z | skip_binary_upload                           | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3876100Z | skip_app_version_update                      | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3876750Z | overwrite_screenshots                        | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3877360Z | sync_screenshots                             | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3877970Z | reject_if_possible                           | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3878570Z | phased_release                               | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3879170Z | reset_ratings                                | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3879800Z | run_precheck_before_submit                   | true                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3880840Z | precheck_default_rule_level                  | warn                                                                                |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3881510Z | ignore_language_directory_validation         | false                                                                               |
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3882840Z +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3883420Z 
2022-04-05T09:24:23.3884330Z [09:24:23]: Making sure the latest version on App Store Connect matches '1.0.149'...
2022-04-05T09:24:23.8417210Z [09:24:23]: Successfully set the version to '1.0.149'
2022-04-05T09:24:23.8517060Z [09:24:23]: Uploading binary to App Store Connect
2022-04-05T09:24:24.4047220Z [09:24:24]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
2022-04-05T09:24:24.4049510Z [09:24:24]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
2022-04-05T09:25:16.7867060Z [09:25:16]: iTunes Transporter successfully finished its job
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1106370Z [09:25:17]: --------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1207620Z [09:25:17]: Successfully uploaded package to App Store Connect. It might take a few minutes until it's visible online.
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1309150Z [09:25:17]: --------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1341770Z [09:25:17]: Finished the upload to App Store Connect
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1343890Z [09:25:17]: Running precheck before submitting to review, if you'd like to disable this check you can set run_precheck_before_submit to false
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1345550Z [09:25:17]: Making sure we pass precheck ‍♀️  before we submit  
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1346100Z 
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1348420Z +--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1349340Z |                        Summary for precheck 2.205.1                        |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1350550Z +--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1351370Z | default_rule_level       | warn                                            |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1352140Z | include_in_app_purchases | false                                           |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1352840Z | app_identifier           | com.bundle.id                      |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1355240Z | api_key_path             | /Users/runner/work/_temp/api_key9Z88UF88N9.json |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1356060Z | platform                 | ios                                             |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1356910Z | use_live                 | false                                           |
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1358240Z +--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1358870Z 
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1359670Z [09:25:17]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
2022-04-05T09:25:17.1360480Z [09:25:17]: Checking app for precheck rule violations
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8126800Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No negative  sentiment
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8244610Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No placeholder text
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8340960Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No mentioning  competitors
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8344540Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No future functionality promises
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8355930Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No words indicating test content
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8360450Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No curse words
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8361750Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: No words indicating your IAP is free
2022-04-05T09:25:31.8362970Z [09:25:31]: ✅  Passed: Incorrect, or missing copyright date
2022-04-05T09:25:34.4012700Z [09:25:34]: ✅  Passed: No broken urls
2022-04-05T09:25:34.4042370Z [09:25:34]: precheck ‍♀️   finished without detecting any potential problems 
2022-04-05T09:25:34.6474110Z [09:25:34]: Selecting the latest build...
2022-04-05T09:25:34.7365550Z [09:25:34]: Waiting for processing on... app_id: 1518025447, app_version: 1.0.149, build_version: 89875, platform: IOS
2022-04-05T09:25:34.8516120Z [09:25:34]: Read more information on why this build isn't showing up yet - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14997
2022-04-05T09:25:34.8519170Z [09:25:34]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:25:49.9763660Z [09:25:49]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:26:05.1568160Z [09:26:05]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:26:20.2713480Z [09:26:20]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:26:35.5406640Z [09:26:35]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:26:50.6913440Z [09:26:50]: Waiting for the build to show up in the build list - this may take a few minutes (check your email for processing issues if this continues)
2022-04-05T09:27:08.5349470Z [09:27:08]: Waiting for App Store Connect to finish processing the new build (1.0.149 - 89875) for IOS
2022-04-05T09:35:49.5224800Z [09:35:49]: Successfully finished processing the build 1.0.149 - 89875 for IOS
2022-04-05T09:35:49.5226290Z [09:35:49]: Selecting build 1.0.149 (89875)...
2022-04-05T09:35:50.6884150Z [09:35:50]: Successfully selected build
2022-04-05T09:35:51.0286440Z [09:35:51]: Successfully updated IDFA declarations on App Store Connect
2022-04-05T09:35:55.2298080Z 
2022-04-05T09:35:55.2298930Z Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
2022-04-05T09:35:55.2299160Z 
2022-04-05T09:35:55.4162970Z /Users/runner/.gem-cache/gems/fastlane-2.205.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/api_client.rb:199:in `handle_response': [!] appStoreVersions with id '8ae9663d-d064-4cd3-ba38-4640068aacb1' is not in valid state. - This resource cannot be reviewed, please check associated errors to see why. (Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse)
2022-04-05T09:35:55.4168360Z The provided entity is missing a required attribute - You must provide a value for the attribute 'whatsNew' with this request
tried with Arguments --release_notes --whatsNew release_notes, whatsNew every time same error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this `You must provide a value for the attribute 'whatsNew' with this request` error, try the following ways:

1. Add `skip_metadata: false`, because it might be causing Fastlane to skip the release notes.
2. Provide new content for all languages supported by application in the background of the Apple connection string.

References: [DELIVER (2.150.0.rc3/4) always ask attribute whatsNew](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16700) and  [You must provide a value for the attribute 'whatsNew' with this request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20100)

Comment: Thank you for that Breathtaking solution, although they have to fix that also, skip metadata is different that what's new, they should be separate, or at least to mention that in their docs, very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

So, I resolved this problem follow my instructions..

1. Delete DeliverFile and metadata folder present in your root folder (if any). Usually that is generated when you run the command

```
fastlane deliver init
```

2. Go to appstoreconnect.com into your project and create a new version and add the what's new note over there and save
3. Go to your project terminal in your local device and run

```
fastlane deliver init
```

again

4. Then run

```
fastlane deliver submit_build -u <email> -a <buildIdentifier> --skip_binary_upload true --skip_metadata true --skip_screenshots true --automatic_release --force
```

Should work... This process with remove all useless thing written in DeliverFile

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue.

Make sure to provide release notes either via metadata file

see more at: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/#metadata

or via `release_notes` param along with your application language (see example below) in the `deliver` action.

```rb
 deliver(
    skip_metadata: false,
    languages: ['en-US'],
    release_notes: {
      "default" => "whats new",
      "en-US" => "whats new",
    },
    ...
)
```

Also make sure to have `en-US` and `default` directories with at least 1 file in your `en-US` in your metadata folder.

This combination has worked for me in fastlane version `2.210.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got it working without any metadata folders. As we wanted to manage the content through AppStore, storing the metadata in the repository was not optimal.
It seems that if the metadata folder is empty, it will only update the parameters that are set in deliver. In the release notes provide all supported languages:

```
deliver(
  submit_for_review: true,
  app_identifier: "com.x",
  app_version: "1",
  build_number: "1",
  automatic_release: false,
  phased_release: true,
  skip_metadata: false,
  skip_screenshots: true,
  skip_binary_upload: true,
  precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
  release_notes: {
    'en-GB' => "Fixes bugs"
  },
  force: true
)
```